# Tabs menu action when parameter is present

Tags: navigation

Building a module in Drupal 10:

The module consists of several pages. All of which are accessed by tabs. The tabs are the same set of tabs for each page within.

The second tab goes to a form for entering data. This form is also used to edit the data. Here are the routes, menu, tasks files

module.routing.yml

```
rmdrs.home:
  path: '/reminders-home'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\rmdrs\Controller\RemindersController::index'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'

rmdrs.reminder_form:
  path: '/reminder-form/{rmdrs_id}'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\rmdrs\Form\ReminderForm'
    rmdrs_id: ''
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

module.links.menu.yml

```
rmdrs.home_menu:
  title: 'Reminder Sys'
  description: 'Go to the Reminder Application Home Page'
  route_name: rmdrs.home
```

module.links.tasks.yml

```
rmdrs.reminders.tabs:
  route_name: rmdrs.home
  title: 'Reminders'
  base_route: rmdrs.reminders.tabs

rmdrs.reminders.form_tab:
  route_name: rmdrs.reminder_form
  title: 'Reminder Form'
  base_route: rmdrs.reminders.tabs
  weight: 2

rmdrs.reminders.categories_tab:
  route_name: rmdrs.categories
  title: 'Manage Categories'
  base_route: rmdrs.reminders.tabs
  weight: 4

rmdrs.reminders.contacts_tab:
  route_name: rmdrs.contacts
  title: 'Manage Contacts'
  base_route: rmdrs.reminders.tabs
  weight: 5

rmdrs.reminders.config_tab:
  route_name: rmdrs.config
  title: 'Configure'
  base_route: rmdrs.reminders.tabs
  weight: 6
```

The parameter rmdrs_id (record ID) for the routing is there to determine if the fields of the form need to be populated. If an entry exists, then the fields populate and the user can edit.

While editing an existing record, if the user hits the tab button for the form, the expected outcome would be a new blank form. However, if the URL contains an ID value when the tab for the form is clicked, it simply reloads the page, WITH the URL still containing the ID, and populates the field.

I attempted to create another route and assign it to the module.links.tasks.yml entry for the form tab, but in doing so, if an ID was in the URL, the entire tab row would not display. My guess is because the route the tab is assigned does not contain a parameter.

The question is, how can I get the tab to always reload a fresh page when clicked, thus ignoring the parameter in the address bar?

---

EDIT:
I created a solution, but am not certain I should use a hook for this. Given that much of the menu coding of this type is done via a .yml file, is this the most optimal/standard way of doing what I am trying to accomplish? If there is a more direct way to do this in the .links files please let me know.

This is what I used in the .module file.

```
function rmdrs_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name, \Drupal\Core\Cache\RefinableCacheableDependencyInterface &$cacheability) {
  // If the current route is 'rmdrs.reminder_form' ensure that if the
  // 'Reminder Form' tab is clicked it always renders a blank form (new page)
  if ($route_name == 'rmdrs.reminder_form') {
    $data['tabs'][0]['rmdrs.reminders.form_tab'] = [
      '#theme' => 'menu_local_task',
      "#active" => TRUE,
      '#link' => [
        'title' => t('Reminder Form'),
        'url' => \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('rmdrs.reminder_form', ['rmdrs_id' => '']),
        'localized_options' => [
          'attributes' => [
            'id' => 'rmdrs_altered_form_tab',
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create Menu Local task plugin as well if you prefer oops code https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/Bhanu951-3103712/-/blob/8.x-dev/tab_examples/src/Plugin/Menu/LocalTask/UserDetailsTab.php?ref_type=heads